# Typescript define array that can contain only specific strings

Tags: typescript

I'm confused to why following errors, I have character interface

```
interface Character {
 race: "ORC" | "ELF" | "HUMAN" | "DWARF"
}
```

And another interface tavern

```
interface Tavern {
  races: Character['race'][]
}
```

Idea here is that races is an array of strings that can only be `"ORC" | "ELF" | "HUMAN" | "DWARF"`

For some reason I get an error when I use it like this

```
const tavern: Tavern = {
   races: ["ORC", "ELF", "HUMAN", "DWARF"]
}
```

Error reads as follows

> [ts]   Type '{ races: string[] }' is not assignable to type 'Tavern'.
>       Types of property 'races' are incompatible.
>         Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '("HUMAN" | "ORC" | "ELF" | "DWARF")[]'.
>           Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"HUMAN" | "ORC" | "ELF" | "DWARF"'.

Comment: 2.9.2, very weird, I'm not sure what else could be causing that error, will look into it more

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get any error either with your exact code. I was going to suggest a helpers function to infer the literal types instead of `string` but something este is at work https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Character%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20race%3A%20%22ORC%22%20%7C%20%22ELF%22%20%7C%20%22HUMAN%22%20%7C%20%22DWARF%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Tavern%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20races%3A%20Character%5B'race'%5D%5B%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20tavern%3A%20Tavern%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20races%3A%20%5B%22ORC%22%2C%20%22ELF%22%2C%20%22HUMAN%22%2C%20%22DWARF%22%5D%0D%0A%7D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this is an old typescript story, you will most likely have to do this:

```
const tavern: Tavern = {
   races: ["ORC", "ELF", "HUMAN", "DWARF"] as Array<Character['race']>
}
```

possibly

```
type Race = "ORC" | "ELF"

const tavern: Tavern = {
   races: ["ORC" as Race, "ELF" as Race]
}
```

this should work

```
enum Race = { ORC, ELF }

interface Tavern {
  races: Race[]
}

const tavern: Tavern = {
   races: [Race.ORC, Race.ELF]
}
```

Comment: That first one did the trick. Is there any source or github issue you could reference that explores this in more depth?

Comment: I am not sure about any references, but the problem is that typescripts treats your array as regular `string[]` initially. Btw, I have updated the answer - enums might be a good choice here, they can hold values as well like `ORC = "ORC"` if you want to have sane interop with other systems

Answer (score 0):

I think this may have been a typescript bug when you wrote the question. [Typescript v5.0.4 (the latest at the time of this answer) compiles your code without issue:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAs5UZKyDeAsAFDLZIBcyARAPIBKq1yAPjQKIAyAYs29QAkAqgFkAggDk%20NACIB1MfV4kAviRKhc8JMgAqcAG7QQBEsjKIIAZyoYsOaAG0A5OQjOAuo4%20r1xBAD2IFZgyGCGxlT6RlAmALympOZuNsiOdIzUADQcPNk0wuJSOdTyirw%20xGrEQA)

```
interface Character {
 race: "ORC" | "ELF" | "HUMAN" | "DWARF"
}

interface Tavern {
  races: Character['race'][]
}

const tavern: Tavern = {
   races: ["ORC", "ELF", "HUMAN", "DWARF"]
}
```